# Python formatting output of even and odd numbers

Tags: python

```
start = int(input("Enter a number: "))

for number in range (1, start + 1):
    if (number % 2 != 0):
        print("{0}".format(number, ','))
```

I have this code that works, but when it outputs, it does so in different lines. How to I get it to display as 1,3,5,...?

Comment: The `print` statement always adds a linefeed. Use `sys.stdout.write()` if you want to stay on the same line for multiple outputs.

Comment: @Grismar or just `print(data,end="")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print you can add the `end` argument:

```
print({0}.format(number), end=",")
```

By default this is "\n" which is a new line.

Comment: how do I remove the final comma after the last output and remove the number 11 if the input is 11?

Comment: i usually print the last thing out of the loop but that's a mess. Try 
print({0},.format(number), end="")
That makes the end just nothing and you add the comma in the string before the format.

Comment: the . before the word format highlights orange, what is wrong with your line of code?

Comment: ah sry my bad you need quotes it's "{0},"

Answer (score 1):

Save your results into an array, say `results`

```
results = []

# your logic here

print(','.join(results))
```

Comment: how do I remove the final comma after the last output and remove the number 11 if the input is 11?

Comment: There shouldn't be a comma after the last element. Care to update your code in your question?